# How to return the n-largest value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to return the second largest value within a dataframe column.

When I use `.nlargest(n)` you can get the individual value of the highest by setting variable `float()` but when you increase `n` above 1 it returns both first and second highest as seen below. I want just the second highest to be set as my variable.

```
n = 2

largest_ja = narr_df.nlargest(n, columns='Rate_Variance')['Rate_Variance'].to_string(index=False)
```

The results below when n = 2. I can not set float(largest_ja) as it is a table

```
2546    46363.899240
9109     9299.873859
```

Comment: just take the second value : narr_df.nlargest(n, columns='Rate_Variance')['Rate_Variance'][1]

Comment: `narr_df.nlargest(n, columns='Rate_Variance')['Rate_Variance'].to_string(index=False).iloc[-1].iloc[0]`

Comment: Thanks. Just require one .iloc[]

Answer (score 0):

You can take the `idxmin()` of the n largest results, so in your case it would be something along that line:
`df.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).idxmin())`

Answer (score 0):

Just add Pandas dataframe around it:

```
pd.DataFrame(df_xls.groupby(['Category','Sub-Category'])['Sales'].sum().groupby(['Category']).nlargest(2))
```

[image]